# Qt iOS: how to return QVideoFrame with type GLTextureHandle from QVideoFilterRunnable

Tags: ios, qt, opengl-es, textures, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to capture camera output frame and process it further in GPU pipeline. For this reason returing frame as a GPU texture is the best option. After inheriting from [QVideoFilterRunnable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideofilterrunnable.html) class received by [run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideofilterrunnable.html#run) method [QVideoFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html) objects has type which is not equal to [QAbstractVideoBuffer::GLTextureHandle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideobuffer.html#HandleType-enum). It's equal to `NoHandle` and I need to do map/unmap and load texture manually by `glTexImage`, which is not good for performance. Is there any control options that can be used to return texture name?

Some notes:

- Looks good on Android. Returned frame is texture so this works like a charm:

  ```
  QVideoFrame* input = ...;
  GLuint texture = input->handle().toUInt(); 
  f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  ```
- It's possible in general, there is iOS texture cache feature:

  ```
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = ...;
  CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(..., pixelBuffer, ..., &textureRef);
  texture = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(textureRef);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`CVPixelBufferRef` can be created manually (I do need to use `map` still):

```
frame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);

CVPixelBufferRef x;
CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    frame.size().width(),
    frame.size().height(),
    kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
    frame.bits(),
    frame.bytesPerLine(),
    nullptr, // releaseCallback
    nullptr, // releaseRefCon
    nullptr, // pixelBufferAttributes
    &x
);
```

Use value of `CVPixelBufferRef` pointer to create cache texture:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureRef texRef;
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    textureCache,
    x,
    NULL, // texture attributes
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    GL_RGBA, // opengl format
    inputW,
    inputH,
    inputPixelFormat,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    0,
    &texRef
);
```

Getting texture name:

```
inputTexId = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texRef);
```