# Qt iOS: change format of received frames from camera

Tags: ios, qt, ios-camera, qtmultimedia

Frames received from [QVideoFilterRunnable::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideofilterrunnable.html#run) method has format [QVideoFrame::Format_NV12](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#PixelFormat-enum) so before load it to GPU texture using `glTexImage` I need to convert it to `BGRA` first. Is there any way to change the output format of camera?

Here is original problem:

- [Qt iOS: how to return QVideoFrame with type GLTextureHandle from QVideoFilterRunnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206507/qt-ios-how-to-return-qvideoframe-with-type-gltexturehandle-from-qvideofilterrun)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Since I'm using QML this is instructions about getting QML object and using it in C++ code. I guess pure C++ stuff will be the same.</sub>

First you need to highlight camera object in QML source:

```
Camera {
  id: camera
  objectName: "CameraObject"
}
```

Get root object of QQuickView:

```
QQuickView view;

QQuickItem* root = view.rootObject();
assert(root != nullptr);
```

Get QML camera:

```
QObject* qmlCamera = root->findChild<QObject*>("CameraObject");
assert(qmlCamera != nullptr);
```

Get C++ camera from QML camera object:

```
QCamera* camera = qvariant_cast<QCamera*>(qmlCamera->property("mediaObject"));
assert(camera != nullptr);
```

Find format you need:

```
QCameraViewfinderSettings bestSetting;
assert(bestSetting.isNull()); // sanity check

auto viewfinderSettings = camera->supportedViewfinderSettings();
for (auto i: viewfinderSettings) {
  if (i.pixelFormat() != QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32) {
    // skip non-ARGB formats
    continue;
  }
  // check i.resolution()
  // several settings with Format_ARGB32 will be available
  // pick the one with resolution which fits best for you

  bestSetting = i;
}
```

Check that something found and apply settings:

```
assert(bestSetting.pixelFormat() == QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32);
camera->setViewfinderSettings(bestSetting);
```

Now view can be shown:

```
view.show();
return app.exec();
```